# Can not connect to tensorboard on my google compute engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-compute-engine, tensorboard

I am trying to connect to tensorboard on my google compute engine instance but it is not working.

I have an anacondo distribution and use:

`tensorboard --logdir=/logs`

to create my tensorboard at default port 6006.

I also allowed HTTP/HTTPS traffic at my instance and also edited my firewall rules to allow traffic at:

`IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:6006
udp:6006`

But, when I try to acess my tensorboard at

http://EXTERNAL_IP:6006

I get a timeout loading.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this type of configuration is related to port communication issues. Go ahead and get all the available ports with nmap, and you should see something as following:

$ nmap -Pn [YOUR IP ADDRESS]
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Once, you confirm if the port "6006" is open, check if it can connect to your server with a telnet:

$ telnet [YOUR IP ADDRESS] [YOUR PORT]
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

If you get "connection refused" make sure not only that this port is "open" but that it's "listening" as well (remember this needs to be configured on your application in your web server). You can check that with a netstat as following:

$ netstat -an | egrep -w “6006”

And you should see something like this (example for port 22):

$ netstat -an | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

If it says 127.0.0.1 on the Local Address column, it means that port is ONLY listening for connections from your PC itself, not from the Internet or network. If it says 0.0.0.0, it means that port is listening on all 'network interfaces' (i.e. your computer, your modem(s) and your network card(s)).
Thus, the IP you need is the one as the example (0.0.0.0), since this means all IPs can reach that specific port. Plus, you must see the “Listen” status.

In addition, make sure to set up properly the [Firewall rules in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) and your software running on the instance itself to allow traffic to/from this port “6006” in specific, either to any instance or to a specific one using [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags).